# Relationship between App Store Version, App Clip Default Experiences and App Clip Advanced Experiences in App Store Connect API

Tags: apple-appclips, app-store-connect-api

According to the App Store Connect API documentation we can get the [Default App Clip Experience for an App Store Version,](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/get_the_default_app_clip_experience_for_an_app_store_version) and since on the App Store Connect website we have a single App Clip section for an iOS App, it seems that an App Store Version can have 0 or 1 Default App Clip Experience.

But there is no direct way of getting the Advanced App Clip Experiences. The only way I can see is by getting the [App Clip](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/app_store/app_clips_and_app_clip_experiences/app_clips) object first for the App, then listing all Default and Advanced App Clip Experiences for that App Clip.

This makes me wonder: are Advanced App Clip Experiences not directly linkes to an App Store Version like the Default App Clip Experience? Does the list of Default App Clip Experiences returned from an App Clip object always contain a single object, or can it be more than one (perhaps older versions linked to old App Store Versions)? What is the relationship between App Store Version, App Clip Default Experiences and App Clip Advanced Experiences?